# MySQL Create Table from UNION of Two tables

Tags: c++, mysql, c, mysql-workbench

I am new to MYSQL and want to create a table(Table_Result) by UNION of 2 given table (Table1,2). In table 1,2 there are some values in column "MEMORY" which are same, but the count of same memory can be same or different as seen below. I want to create the new table(like table_result) on the basis of "MEMORY" column which has maximum of the count of memory with relative columns in front. The table with memory count less as compared with other table, will have other columns (NAME,CONTENT or NAME1,CONTENT1) filled with "NA" (see table_result).

Any idea how can I write the Mysql query script to get the result. Thanking you for your help.

BR//
RG

```
TABLE1
MEMORY      NAME            CONTENT
MEM 0110H   Systemkennung   DB01
MEM 0110H   Hauptversion    DB03
MEM 0110H   Unterversion    DB00
MEM 0110H   Patchlevel      DB04
MEM 0200H   Steuerkanal1    DB01
MEM 0200H   Steuerkanal2    DB01
MEM 0200H   Steuerkanal3    DB01
MEM 0260H   Steuerkanal35   DB01
MEM 0210H   BUE-Gruppe      DB01
MEM 0210H   Licht-Gruppe1   DB01

TABLE2
MEMORY      NAME1           CONTENT1
MEM 0110H   System          DB01
MEM 0110H   Hauptversion1   DB02
MEM 0200H   Steuerkanal11   DB01
MEM 0200H   Steuerkanal22   DB06
MEM 0200H   Steuerkanal34   DB05
MEM 0200H   Steuerkanal35   DB04
MEM 0260H   Steuerkanal36   DB02
MEM 0210H   BUE-Gruppe      DB01

TABLE_RESULT
MEMORY       NAME           CONTENT     NAME1           CONTENT1
MEM 0110H    Systemkennung  DB01        System          DB01
MEM 0110H    Hauptversion   DB03        Hauptversion1   DB02
MEM 0110H    Unterversion   DB00        NA              NA
MEM 0110H    Patchlevel     DB04        NA              NA
MEM 0200H    Steuerkanal1   DB01        Steuerkanal11   DB01
MEM 0200H    Steuerkanal2   DB01        Steuerkanal22   DB06
MEM 0200H    Steuerkanal3   DB01        Steuerkanal34   DB05
MEM 0200H    NA             NA          Steuerkanal35   DB04
MEM 0260H    Steuerkanal35  DB01        Steuerkanal36   DB02
MEM 0210H    BUE-Gruppe     DB01        BUE-Gruppe      DB01
MEM 0210H    Licht-Gruppe1  DB01        NA              NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  ifnull(a.MEMORY, b.MEMORY) AS MEMORY,
  ifnull(a.NAME, 'NA') AS NAME,
  ifnull(a.CONTENT, 'NA') AS CONTENT,
  ifnull(b.NAME, 'NA') AS NAME1,
  ifnull(b.CONTENT, 'NA') AS CONTENT1
FROM TABLE1 AS a
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 AS b ON a.MEMORY = b.MEMORY
UNION
SELECT
  ifnull(a.MEMORY, b.MEMORY) AS MEMORY,
  ifnull(a.NAME, 'NA') AS NAME,
  ifnull(a.CONTENT, 'NA') AS CONTENT,
  ifnull(b.NAME, 'NA') AS NAME1,
  ifnull(b.CONTENT, 'NA') AS CONTENT1
FROM TABLE1 AS a
RIGHT JOIN TABLE2 AS b ON a.MEMORY = b.MEMORY
```

Comment: I am sorry for asking very basic question. But what is "a" and "b" here?Also, how can thiy query create new table which stores the result.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer comes out to be like below:

```
MEM 0110H, Systemkennung1, DB 01, Systemkennung11, DB 01
MEM 0110H, Systemkennung2, DB 01, Systemkennung11, DB 01
MEM 0110H, Systemkennung3, DB 01, Systemkennung11, DB 01
MEM 0110H, Systemkennung4, DB 01, Systemkennung11, DB 01
MEM 0110H, Systemkennung1, DB 01, Systemkennung12, DB 01
MEM 0110H, Systemkennung2, DB 01, Systemkennung12, DB 01
MEM 0110H, Systemkennung3, DB 01, Systemkennung12, DB 01
MEM 0110H, Systemkennung4, DB 01, Systemkennung12, DB 01
MEM 0110H, Systemkennung1, DB 01, Systemkennung13, DB 01
MEM 0110H, Systemkennung2, DB 01, Systemkennung13, DB 01
MEM 0110H, Systemkennung3, DB 01, Systemkennung13, DB 01
MEM 0110H, Systemkennung4, DB 01, Systemkennung13, DB 01
MEM 0200H, Systemkennung5, DB 01, Systemkennung14, DB 01
MEM 0200H, Systemkennung6, DB 01, Systemkennung14, DB 01
MEM 0200H, Systemkennung7, DB 01, Systemkennung14, DB 01
MEM 0200H, Systemkennung5, DB 01, Systemkennung15, DB 01
MEM 0200H, Systemkennung6, DB 01, Systemkennung15, DB 01
MEM 0200H, Systemkennung7, DB 01, Systemkennung15, DB 01
MEM 0200H, Systemkennung5, DB 01, Systemkennung16, DB 01
MEM 0200H, Systemkennung6, DB 01, Systemkennung16, DB 01
MEM 0200H, Systemkennung7, DB 01, Systemkennung16, DB 01
MEM 0200H, Systemkennung5, DB 01, Systemkennung17, DB 01
MEM 0200H, Systemkennung6, DB 01, Systemkennung17, DB 01
MEM 0200H, Systemkennung7, DB 01, Systemkennung17, DB 01
MEM 0260H, Systemkennung8, DB 01, Systemkennung18, DB 01
MEM 0210H, Systemkennung9, DB 01, Systemkennung19, DB 01
MEM 0210H, Systemkennun10, DB 01, Systemkennung19, DB 01
```

Comment: Do you mean to join on MEMORY and CONTENT? IE, these 2 cols have to be same ?

Comment: Only the column MEMORY is the one for both tables which can have the same values. I do not have to check for the other columns. It is like if I have a 2 same values of MEMORY in table1 and those 3 same values in table2 then my resultant table will have 3 values and the table1 other columns will add NA NA in the NAME and CONTENTS column.